# How to merge array and preserve keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$array2 = array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6, 'a' => 'new value', '123' => 456);
```

I want to merge them and keep the keys and the order and not re-index!!

How to get like this?

```
Array
(
    [a] => new value
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
    [123] => 456
)
```

I try to array_merge() but it will not be preserved the keys:

```
print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));

Array
(
    [a] => 'new value'
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
    [0] => 456
)
```

I try to the union operator but it will not overwriting that element:

```
print_r($array1 + $array2);

Array
(
    [a] => 1   <-- not overwriting
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
    [123] => 456
)
```

I try to swapped place but the order is wrong, not my need:

```
print_r($array2 + $array1);

Array
(
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
    [a] => new value 
    [123] => 456
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```

***I dont want to use a loop, is there a way for high performance?***

Comment: Dont you just flip the order of your array merge? array_merge($array2, $array1);

Comment: The problem with array_merge() is that it sees the `"123"` key, and interprets it as numeric, which gets reindexed.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php):

```
$array1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$array2 = array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6, 'a' => 'new value', '123' => 456);
print_r(array_replace($array1, $array2));
```

Available since PHP 5.3.

**Update**

You can also use the union [array operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php); it works for older versions and might actually be faster too:

```
print_r($array2 + $array1);
```

Comment: My solution would act as a pre 5.3 monkey patch for that function

Comment: Note that `$array2 + $array1` will preserve the values of the first array instead the second one, as one would expect.

Comment: @JavierS yeah, that's why i inverted the order in that example vs the first :)

Answer (score 6):

Let suppose we have 3 arrays as below.

```
$a = array(0=>['label'=>'Monday','is_open'=>1],1=>['label'=>'Tuesday','is_open'=>0]);

$b = array(0=>['open_time'=>'10:00'],1=>['open_time'=>'12:00']); 

$c = array(0=>['close_time'=>'18:00'],1=>['close_time'=>'22:00']);
```

Now, if you want to merge all these array and want a final array that have all array's data under key 0 in 0 and 1 in 1 key as so on.

Then you need to use **array_replace_recursive** PHP function, as below.

```
$final_arr = array_replace_recursive($a, $b , $c);
```

The result of this will be as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Monday
            [is_open] => 1
            [open_time] => 10:00
            [close_time] => 18:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Tuesday
            [is_open] => 0
            [open_time] => 12:00
            [close_time] => 22:00
        )

)
```

Hope the solution above, will best fit your requirement!!

Answer (score 4):

@Jack uncovered the native function that would do this but since it is only available in php 5.3 and above this should work to emulate this functionality on pre 5.3 installs

```
  if(!function_exists("array_replace")){
      function array_replace(){
         $args = func_get_args();
         $ret = array_shift($args);
         foreach($args as $arg){
             foreach($arg as $k=>$v){
                $ret[(string)$k] = $v;
             }
         }
         return $ret;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I dont want to use a loop, is there a way for high performance?

Comment: I can't think of one that will meet the requirement of numeric keys. Don't count out the solution though, I don't think the loop is going to result in the performance suck that you imagine it will.

Comment: You could optimize this a bit by setting `$ret` to the first array directly, and then merging the others on top of that.

Comment: @jcsanyi Good call ... I altered my answer to include your optimization and changed the wording to reference jack's solution as the native way and mine as the fallback for pre 5.3 installs

Answer (score 3):

`array_replace_recursive()` or `array_replace()` is the function you are looking for

```
$array1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$array2 = array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6, 'a' => 'new value', '123' => 456);


var_dump(array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/sXkLnC)

Answer (score -2):

I think this might help if i understand properly:

```
foreach ($i = 0, $num = count($array2); $i < $num; $i++)
{
  $array = array_merge($array1, $arrar2[$i]);
}
```