# PHP merge 2 arrays with different number of elements, $keys from one, $values from another

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge 2 arrays together that have a different number of elements, using the keys from one and the values from another where/if the keys match. The array that contains the desired values may have less elements in it although I would like to retain the resulting empty keys from the original array. For example:

*//Array that contains keys I would like to retain*

`$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);`

*//Array that contains values I'd like to use*

`$arr2 = array(01=>123, 03=>123, 05=>123, 07=>123, 09=>123, 11=>123);`

*//The desired result with some valueless elements*

`$results = array(01=>123, 02, 03=>123, 04, 05=>123, 06, 07=>123, 08, 09=>123, 10, 11=>123, 12);`

As you can see the results array retains 12 elements but only applies values to where the keys from the 2 arrays match.

I have tried `$results = array_intersect_key($arr1 + $arr2, $arr2);` among other PHP functions as well as:

```
for ($i=1; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    if (isset($arr2[$i])) {
        $arr3[] = $arr2[$i];
    } else {
        $arr3[] = $arr1[$i];
    }
}

print_r($arr3);
```

No luck as yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You realise that values of `08` and `09` won't be what most people expect, but will actually be `0`.... numbers beginning with 0 are treated as octal values

Comment: Think I understand your comment and have edited accordingly. Many thanks. Any idea of a solution?

Comment: So, are the _values_ in `$arr1` supposed to be the _keys_ in `$results`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes that's exactly right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge array and preserve keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462354/how-to-merge-array-and-preserve-keys)

Answer (score 2):

For arrays like this

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
$arr2 = array(1=>123, 3=>123, 5=>123, 7=>123, 9=>123, 11=>123);
```

this should work.

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key) {
    $results[$key] = isset($arr2[$key]) ? $arr2[$key] : null;
}
```

or using some other PHP functions:

```
$results = array_replace(array_fill_keys($arr1, null), $arr2);
```

Comment: Never noticed `array_replace()` in the list of array functions before, thanks.

Comment: I just came across `array_replace()` in another answer a couple of days ago, and I had never noticed it before either.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Array that contains keys I would like to retain
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

//Array that contains values I'd like to use
$arr2 = array(1=>123, 3=>123, 5=>123, 7=>123, 9=>123, 11=>123);

$result = array_fill_keys(
    $arr1,
    null
);
array_walk(
    $result,
    function(&$value, $key) use($arr2) {
        $value = (isset($arr2[$key])) ? $arr2[$key] : null;
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First set your `$arr1`'s values to `false` to retain just the keys:
`$arr1 = array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr1), false);` Or if you're generating `$arr1` yourself, define it as such to start with: `$arr1 = Array(false, false, false, false /* etc. */);`

Now use the array union operator:

`$result = $arr2 + $arr1;`

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays — from the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Then if required sort the array by key: `ksort($array);`

Comment: "using the keys from one and the values from another"

Comment: Thanks @rjdown, I've added that in now too