# How to load option's id from database in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I tried to load my options from database, my value set correctly but id loaded incorrect :

Controller :

```
    $country_list = contry::lists('name','id');
    $country_list = array_merge(array('0' => 'Please Select...'),   $country_list->toArray());
```

View :

```
    {!! Form::select('country_id',$country_list,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Database :

```
"1"=>"USA"
"2"=>"IRAN"
--> "5"=>"ENGLAND" <--
```

Load in browser :

```
"0"=>"Please Select"
"1"=>"USA"
"2"=>"IRAN"
--> "3"=>"ENGLAND" <--
```

Inspect elements Result :

```
<select class="form-control" name="country_id">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">IRAN</option>
    <option value="3">ENGLAND</option
</select>
```

I need option id same to id column in database

Comment: please post your front-end code

Comment: yes please. can you?

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: Your question is fine, shows exactly what the problem is. You'll find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462354/how-to-merge-array-and-preserve-keys

Comment: @JoelHinz I asked about Laravel framework

Comment: @RohitKhatri I can't explain more..., what you need to know?!

Comment: @AbolfazlYavari I know that. The problem is that you're merging arrays without preserving keys. That has nothing to do with Laravel. Read the answer in the link I provided, it shows you *exactly* what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_merge reindexes the merged array, so that's your problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
"Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array."

To avoid that use

```
$country_list = [0 => 'Please Select...'] + $country_list->toArray();
```

Or just:

```
$country_list = contry::lists('name','id')->toArray();
$country_list[0] = 'Please Select...';
```

Answer (score 1):

array_merge will override the key so use plus (+) to combine the array. I think it will solve your issue:

```
$country_list = array('0' => 'Please Select...') + $country_list->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake here with array merging:

`$country_list = array_merge(array('0' => 'Please Select...'),   $country_list->toArray());`

You should do like:

`$country_list = array('0' => 'Please Select...') + $country_list->toArray();`

to not override keys.