# Subtraction of two array values for same keys and and get result both matched and non-matched value in php

Tags: php

I have two arrays like $a and $b. I want do subtract from $a to $b for the same keys. Also I wanna see the non-matched key of the both array with the subtraction result.
Only matched key will be subtracted. Is it possible without using foreach loop? Not Mandatory that it must be solve without loop. But better if it would be possible without loop.Sample Array is in the below.

```
$a=Array
(

    [1] => 4.00
    [2] => 3.00
    [3] => 8.00
    [4] => 4.88
    [5] => 7.88
    [10] => 17.88
)
$b=Array
(
    [1] => 2.00
    [3] => 4.00
    [4] => 2.88
    [7] => 5.00
    [8] => 6.00    
)
```

I wanna the result like

```
$result=array(

[1] => 2.00
[2] => 3.00
[3] => 4.00
[4] => 2.00
[5] => 7.88
[7] => 5.00
[8] => 6.00
[10] => 17.88

);
```

My code is:

```
$res1=$res2=$res3=array();
foreach( $a as $k1=>$v1 ){
     foreach($b as $k2=>$v2){
         if($k1==$k2){
            $res1[$k1]=$v2-$v1;
         }else{
            $res2[$k2]=v2;
            $res3[$k1]=v1;
         }
     }
}

$res[]=array_merge($res1,$res2,$res3);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($res); echo "</pre>";
```

But It doesn't give the proper result which I want.

Comment: Shouldn't 7 be -5 and 8 should be -6? Why are those positive. The rest follow the pattern of $a - $b but those don't

Comment: Actually positive negative doesnt matter for my purpose. Logically it should be negative.

Comment: *Is it possible without using foreach loop?* why?

Comment: Already I have used  many loops in my script thats why i wanna avoid foreach. By the way, not mandatory to avoid foreach loops but better if it can be avoided.

Comment: Shardj would you please help me?

Comment: There's no way to do it without a loop.  Even if you manage to use a built-in PHP function of some sort, the function will still be looping through the arrays to get the job done.  It's also not going to impact speed in any measurable amount, even with thousands of iterations.  If you'd like some help on a specific part of your code, you're going to need to post an attempt to do this yourself.

Comment: No problem, please do it by foreach loop.. I need help..

Comment: If you'd like some help on a specific part of your code, you're going to need to post an attempt to do this yourself.  SO is not a code writing service, nor intended to answer your homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try With the below code. Hope it will give your desired output.

```
$res1=$res2=$res3=array();
    foreach( $a as $k1=>$v1 ){
        if(isset($b[$k1])){
            $res1[$k1]=$a[$k1]-$b[$k1];     
        }else{
            $res2[$k1]=$v1;     
        }   
    }

    $res3=array_diff_key($b, $a);
    $result = array_replace_recursive($res1,$res2,$res3);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, `array_walk` is still essentially a loop as it iterates over each element. I've documented the code at each step but the basic idea is to create a merged array and then to alter the values for the duplicate items. There are more efficient ways to go about this, but this illustrates a basic methodology.

I should also point out that because this is using `array_walk` and an anonymous function (closure), we have to pass in any variables that it needs (`... use (...)`). If you were to use a `foreach` loop (or `for`), you wouldn't need to do this and you could access `$output`, `$first`, and `$second` directly.

https://3v4l.org/WD0t4#v7125

```
<?php

$first = [
    1 => 4.00,
    2 => 3.00,
    3 => 8.00,
    4 => 4.88,
    5 => 7.88,
    10 => 17.88
];

$second = [
    1 => 2.00,
    3 => 4.00,
    4 => 2.88,
    7 => 5.0,
    8 => 6.00
];

// Merge the 2 original arrays and preserve the keys
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/17462354/296555
// The duplicate items' value will be clobbered at this point but we don't care. We'll set them in the `array_walk` function.
$output = $first + $second;

// Create an array of the duplicates. We'll use these keys to calculate the difference.
$both = array_intersect_key($first, $second);

// Foreach element in the duplicates, calculate the difference.
// Notice that we're passing in `&$output` by reference so that we are modifying the underlying object and not just a copy of it.
array_walk($both, function($value, $key) use (&$output, $first, $second) {
    $output[$key] = $first[$key] - $second[$key];
});

// Finally, sort the final array by its keys.
ksort($output);

var_dump($output);

// Output
//array (size=8)
//  1 => float 2
//  2 => float 3
//  3 => float 4
//  4 => float 2
//  5 => float 7.88
//  7 => float 5
//  8 => float 6
//  10 => float 17.88
```

And the obligatory condensed version using a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php

$first = [
    1 => 4.00,
    2 => 3.00,
    3 => 8.00,
    4 => 4.88,
    5 => 7.88,
    10 => 17.88
];

$second = [
    1 => 2.00,
    3 => 4.00,
    4 => 2.88,
    7 => 5.0,
    8 => 6.00
];

$output = $first + $second;
foreach (array_keys(array_intersect_key($first, $second)) as $key) {
    $output[$key] = $first[$key] - $second[$key];
}
ksort($output);

var_dump($output);

// Output
//array (size=8)
//  1 => float 2
//  2 => float 3
//  3 => float 4
//  4 => float 2
//  5 => float 7.88
//  7 => float 5
//  8 => float 6
//  10 => float 17.88
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close!

```
$count = count($a) + count($b);  // figure out how many times we need to loop - count total # of elements

for ( $key = 1; $key <= $count ; $key++ )
{
    if ( isset($a[$key]) && isset($b[$key]) )  $result[$key] = number_format(abs($a[$key] - $b[$key]), 2);
    elseif ( isset($a[$key]) ) $result[$key] = number_format($a[$key], 2);
    elseif ( isset($b[$key]) ) $result[$key] = number_format($b[$key], 2);
}
```

The "number_format" and "abs" functions are simply to make the output look exactly like you said you needed.